# Securest way to work with a remote GitHub repo on a multiuser Linux server

Tags: linux, github, ssh-keys

I'am currently working on a multi-user Linux server where i have a non sudo user. Also I have a GitHub account where I have a private Repo. Now I want to work with this repo remotely from the Linux Server.
When I'am working with a personal machine I would create a SSH-Key and add the private key to my SSH-Agent and the public key to my GitHub account.
I trust the other users and the admin of the Linux server but nevertheless I want to make the access to my GitHub account as secure as possible.
My question now is, if there are some suggestions or maybe "finished solutions" on what I could do to make this more secure.

Comment: Secure against what?  Also, have you read this: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-is-ssh-agent-forwarding-and-how-do-you-use-it/ ?

Comment: Thank you @Slartibartfast, this is a good hint.